# Can't access Alamofire Request body

Tags: swift4, ios12

I'm facing a problem while requesting from server, everything was fine 
suddenly the Alamofire.request can't access responseJSON and can't access the body of the function and it returns , what I have to do?
I'm using multi Alamofire request in the navigationController but after two or three requests this happens! 
I'm really in trouble please help me!

this code can't execute

```
    let group = DispatchGroup()
    group.enter()
    Alamofire.request(url, method: .get, parameters: nil, 
      encoding: 
        JSONEncoding.default, headers: header as? HTTPHeaders)
        .responseJSON { (response) in
            if response.result.isSuccess{
                if let response = response.result.value {

                    let json = JSON(response)
                    self.updateAnswers(json: json)
                    print(json.arrayValue)
                    group.leave()
                }
            }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it’s not successful, you should dive in and take a look at the error that was returned. You might even want to look at the body of the response (if its a development server, it might provide some useful error messages in the body of the response).

```
let group = DispatchGroup()
group.enter()
Alamofire.request(...)
    .responseJSON { response in
        defer { group.leave() }

        switch response.result {
        case .failure(let error):
            print(error)
            print(response.response ?? "no HTTPURLResponse")
            if let data = response.data {
                if let string = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8) {
                    print(string)
                } else {
                    print(data as NSData)
                }
            } else {
                print("no data")
            }

        case .success(let json):
            print(json)
        }
}
```

By the way, I’d suggest moving the `leave` call outside of any `if`/`switch` statement because you want to make sure your dispatch group is satisfied regardless of whether it was successful or not.

But, bottom line, you won’t be able to diagnose the problem until you start to look at precisely what error was returned.